# How to fix a TypeError saying 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

My wave.py file:

```
import User_Account

username = input('Username: ')
password = input('Password: ')

Session = User_Account(username, password)
```

My User_Account.py file:

```
import tidalapi

class User_Account:

    def __init__(self, username_, password_):
        self.username = username_
        self.password = password_

    def login(self):
        session = tidalapi.Session()
        return session.login(self.username, self.password)
```

When I run the above code in PyCharm I get the following error.

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I am reading examples of OOP in Python - [such as this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/object-oriented-programming) - and even when I run their code, I get the same error. I've searched for it here and on Google but the solutions don't seem to fix the issue.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your time and if there is anything I can supply to improve my question, please don't hesitate.

EDIT: Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/doug/PycharmProjects/Wave/wave.py", line 6, in <module>
    Session = User_Account(username, password)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Something is wonky here, please give the full traceback. `import User_Account` shouldn't work because the module name is all lowercase

Comment: To import class `User_Account` from module `user_account`, you should do `from user_account import User_Account`

Comment: Huh, well TIL that case sensitivity is [platform-dependent](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/) with imports

Comment: @roganjosh Why does that chart say "brrrrrrrrrr"? Does it mean that combo isn't possible?

Comment: @wjandrea I'm not entirely sure tbh. Since I've only just discovered it, I'll need to play a bit when I get time but I'm now on my phone

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you are bringing in the module but not specifying the class you want from that module.

I think the following change to your wave.py would fix this...

```
Session = User_Account.User_Account(username, password)
```

Even better, rather than importing User_Account, you might want to say...

```
from User_Account import User_Account
```

If you do this, your "Session ="  call will work as you currently have it.

Comment: @DMellon: FWIW, the [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) in the [PEP 8 coding guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for packages and modules suggests "Modules should have short, all-lowercase names", which means your `User_Account.py` script really ought to be renamed `user_account.py`.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly like the error says, a module is not callable. It looks like you meant to run `from user_account import User_Account` instead of `import User_Account`.

Note that `import User_Account` would fail on a case-sensitive platform like Linux. If you did actually want to import `user_account.py` you would write `import user_account`.